# Vimrc customization for googlecl use

Tags: vim

I've started using google docs for collaborating with others who can't/won't break down and learn my standard vim/latex/git workflow for writing and collaborating.  Google has a command line interface called [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) which allows you to call something like:

```
$ googlecl docs edit --title "Some Document" --editor vim
```

which allows me to edit my google docs in vim.

What I'd really like though is to be able to change some vim settings if the file I'm working on is a google docs file.  The easiest example here is changing the line wrapping. Is there a way to use an `augroup` type of construct for googlecl documents?  Is this even possible currently, or would this require me poking around in the source?

Comment: What sort of filename do you end up with? Some globbable path you could match? (You'll want `au BufNewFile,BufRead *pattern* *command*`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about creating a very simple bash script in `~/bin` that looks like this?

```
#!/bin/sh
vim -c 'set ft=google_docs' $@
```

Save that as `~/bin/google_vim` and do `chmod +x ~/bin/google_vim`.  Then create a file:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/google_docs.vim
```

with the settings that you need (e.g. `set nowrap` or whatever) and start the editor with:

```
googlecl docs edit --title "Some Document" --editor google_vim
```

(assuming `~/bin` is in your path: if not you could probably do `--editor ~/bin/google_vim`)